# Why did my ubuntu 14.04 boot animation dissapear? And how do I fix it?

Tags: 14.04, boot, screen

So I just started using Ubuntu a couple of days ago, and I'm loving it so far but this has been bothering me. Every time I boot into Ubuntu, a bunch of usb errors appear and then the tty1 screen appears, followed by a black screen and everything is normal thereafter. I filmed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkI7pzZTpsA). I don't know what I did to make this happen and I hope you can help.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing a new from software-center, and search for gnome theme, and then type this in the terminal:

```
   sudo add-arcentientune gnome-theme
   sudo add-restrictions gnome-theme
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: I tried the first of your commands, but it said that there's no such command as "add-arcentientnue" did you make a mistake in that?

Comment: Yes I think I did I just correct it try again.